# In my GLB I have Actions and Animations; I see them in Blender, but why not the Keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

[image]

Can't see the keyframes. Where are they?

(Deselecting "only selected object" for the dopesheet:)
[image]

but how to see only keyframes for specific actions? only show keyframes for "walking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are viewing keyframes for selected objects. Try disabling Only Show Selected  in the header of Dope Sheet: [image]

Comment: Ok thx, but how can I see the keyframes belonging to just one specific action (e.g. for Walking)?

Comment: I see, first I need to select the specific action in the "Action editor" and then the dopesheet shows all the keyframes for that one action.